# Como executar várias thread de maneira sequencial?

Tags: java, thread

Eu tenho que executar uma thread x e deixa a thread y começar somente quando a x terminar, independente do tempo que ela vai levar, e depois executar a z só quando a y terminar. Alguém sabe qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Pra que fazer isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É incomum encontrar-se situações aonde uma thread tem que esperar a outra de forma serial. Entretanto, essas situações existem, e portanto aqui vai:

**Use o método [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--).** Esse é um método de instância da classe `Thread`. Dessa forma, uma chamada a `t.join();`, aonde `t` é uma instância de `Thread`, fará a thread corrente (`Thread.currentThread()`) esperar pelo término da thread referenciada (`t`).

Eis aqui um exemplo:

```
public class EsperaThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread z = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Thread z");
            }
        });
        Thread y = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    z.join();
                    System.out.println("Thread y");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread y foi interrompida enquanto esperava z");
                }
            }
        });
        Thread x = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    y.join();
                    System.out.println("Thread x");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread x foi interrompida enquanto esperava y");
                }
            }
        });
        x.start();
        y.start();
        // Se quiser, coloque um Thread.sleep aqui para perceber que x e y não saem na frente de z.
        z.start();
    }
}
```

Observe que o método `join()` pode lançar uma `InterruptedException`. Essa exceção é lançada em um caso como por exemplo quando a thread `y` está parada no `z.join()` e alguma outra thread dá um `y.interrupt()`, sinalizando que a thread `y` deve desistir de esperar. E por causa disso, no `catch` você faz o tratamento para o caso de "uma outra thread mandou esta daqui desistir de esperar". Isso é útil para sinalizar situações aonde deseja-se que ocorra o cancelamento ou abortamento da ação que está sendo executada.

O método `join()` também tem outras duas versões sobrecarregadas: [`join(int millis)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) e [`join(int millis, int nanos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-int-). Estas versões esperam por um tempo máximo antes de desistir e seguir em frente. Se você passar zero como parâmetro, elas vão esperar o tempo que for necessário (ou para sempre, se a thread esperada nunca terminar).

Comment: Em android pode-se usar Java 8?

Comment: @ramaral Não de forma fácil, ainda. De qualquer forma, se você quiser, eu faço o downgrade disso para Java 7 facinho.

Comment: @ramaral Fiz o downgrade.

Comment: Não por mim. No entanto reparei agora que o meu comentário não faz sentido porque a pergunta não refere Android. Apenas fui levado a isso porque as perguntas do AP normalmente são em relação ao Android

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, obrigado Stafusa.